# Is it already 18th Dec!

Tags: discussion, support

In India current time `17th Dec 4:30PM which is +5.30 GMT`.

I got a ***A New Hope*** hat.

How i got this hat!

Is there any other rules to get this hat!

[image]

Comment: I just came here to ask the same question. I know  It's a fun feature and
does not need to be perfect , but curious to know the answer :)

Comment: Short answer: Timezones. Long answer can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early).

Comment: got it thanks Clive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum difference is at least 26 hours, as there are time zones for GMT-12 all the way to GMT+14. With DST, that may go up to 27 hours.